# PHP/SQL Text Match to a Field OR In String in a second field

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a PHP/MySQL app and I'm trying to match text to one of two fields.
My database has `primaryname` and `alternatename`: `primaryname` is a single word of text. `alternatename` is a comma separated list.

It works for matching primary name, but the OR part is causing the entire query to fail.

Working part:

```
$sql_statement  = "SELECT primaryname, alternatename, notes, imageurl, status ";
$sql_statement .= "FROM fish ";
$sql_statement .= "WHERE primaryname LIKE '".$fishname."'";
```

Here's what I have (not working):

```
$sql_statement  = "SELECT primaryname, alternatename, notes, imageurl, status ";
$sql_statement .= "FROM fish ";
$sql_statement .= "WHERE primaryname LIKE '".$fishname."' OR alternatename LIKE %'".$fishname."'%";
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

(P.S. Sorry if the formatting didn't work right. This is my first question on *Stack Overflow* after lurking for many years. Couldn't find an answer to this one.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd leave this in a comment but reputation not high enough.

It looks like you % signs shoud be in the single quotes '%".$fishname."%'

Comment: Duh! Working now. Thanks Matt.